# VIM: How to open another file from same location as an already open file

Tags: vim

Let's say I am in my home directory. I open a file that is present in some deep nested directory structure:

```
vim /some/really/long/path/file.txt
```

Now, within vim, I want to start a vertical split with another file from that same long location (but I don't want to change the current directory to that path, I still want to be in the home directory).

A layman (like me) will do something like:

```
:vsp /some/really/long/path/file2.txt
```

But I want to find out from all you VIM geniuses out there, is there an easier way to do this?

On the same note, if I had multiple files already open residing in different paths, can VIM automatically assign some sort of internal variables to all the locations? And then when I want to start a new VSP or SP with one of the files from one of those locations, I simply use those internal variables?

Comment: If you expect opening files from the same location, you can do :cd /long/path/to/the/files/you/want and then just go :e file1, :e file2 etc.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the cd command. I was just wondering if VIM maintains an accessible list of locations of already open files, that I can cycle through without doing "cd" or typing full path every time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
:vs %:p:h/otherfile
```

as `%:p:h` gives you the path of the current file.
See `:help %:p` for more info.

Comment: Marking this response as the answer, as it explains exactly what's going on with that %:p:h thingy :)

Answer (score 3):

Edit another file in the same directory:

```
:vs %<Tab><C-w><C-w><C-w>file2<Tab>
```

With a mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :vs <C-R>=expand('%:p:h')<CR>
```

Comment: This is perfect. After posting my question, I found this same answer on vim.wikia.com as well. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easy_edit_of_files_in_the_same_directory

Answer (score 0):

If you like more navigation than typing the commands, a convenient option could be the use of the embedded **Explore** command, which opens a window with the list files in the directory of the file in current buffer. Then you can navigate with the cursors and press **v** when over the file you want to open in a vertical split.

A convenient way is to map the **Explore** command, like:

```
" open embedded file system navigator
map <leader>\ :Explore<cr>
```

Press **<leader>\** and navigate to the file, then press **v**.

With some versions of vim, the Explore window stays open after pressing **v** -- in that case, if you want to avoid extra burden to close the **Explore** window, you can do first the vertical split with **:vsp**, invoke **:Expore** and open the desired file by pressing **Enter**.